# Determining Current Call Stack (For Diagnostic Purposes)

Tags: java, stack-trace

For diagnostic purposes I sometimes need to store the call stack that lead to a given state transition (such as granting a lock, committing a transaction, etc.) so that when something goes wrong later I can find out who originally triggered the state transition.

Currently, the only way I am aware of to retrieve the call stack looks like the following code snippet, which I consider terribly ugly:

```
StackTraceElement[] cause;
try {
  throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
  cause = e.getStackTrace();
}
```

Does somebody know of a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I think you can get the same thing with:

```
StackTraceElement[] cause = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

Comment: As @nyx noted in their answer below, Java 9 introduced StackWalker, which might have better performance any some cases (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49091729).

Answer (score 17):

Well, you can improve it slightly by not actually throwing the exception.

```
Exception ex = new Exception();
ex.fillInStackTrace();
StackTraceElement[] cause = ex.getStackTrace();
```

Actually, I just checked: the constructor calls `fillInStackTrace()` already. So you can simplify it to:

```
StackTraceElement[] cause = new Exception().getStackTrace();
```

This is actually what [`Thread.getStackTrace()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()) does if it's called on the current thread, so you might prefer using it instead.

Comment: No need for `fillInStackTrace` (although it is easy to read its API docs backwards).

Comment: The .class file/source I'm looking at right now calls native `Thread.dumpThreads()` rather than using a dummy exception.  OpenJDK- 11+28_windows-x64_bin.  Hyphen, plus, underscore, hyphen, underscore?  <Dad>I'm not mad, I'm just disappointed.</Dad>

Answer (score 3):

If you want it as a String and use Apache Commons:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(new Throwable())
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a new option since JDK 9: StackWalker

It isn't as expensive as Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().

see also [How Expensive is Thread.getStackTrace()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347828/how-expensive-is-thread-getstacktrace)