# Does getting a stack trace for a thread have impact on its performance?

Tags: java, multithreading

Does getting a stack trace of a Java thread calling `Thread.getStackTrace()` have any impact on its performace?

EDIT: for monitoring purposes I would like to get stack traces of some monitored threads. I understand that parsing the stack of a thread could be a time consuming operation. In my case the most critical is that the performance of the thread for which the stack trace is being constructed is not affected.

Comment: from within the thread or from another thread?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there will be performance impact when you try to getStackTrace(). It need to back track stack dump of this thread. Here is interesting SO discussion on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347828/how-expensive-is-thread-getstacktrace).