# How can i see every method called in a Java Application?

Tags: java, jvm, monitoring, callstack

Is there a way to get textual output of every method invoked by the JVM at runtime?

Comment: There's probably a better way of getting what you want. Are you trying to debug something?

Comment: Tracing the call stack of runtime code with a lot of reflection (hadoop).

Comment: Have you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706292/java-determining-current-call-stack-for-diagnostic-purposes?

Comment: Is there a specific issue you're trying to debug?

Comment: specifically, i want to see how many times every method in a distributed system is being called.  I want to see which operations in my classes are most used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Eclipse** you can right click the method and choose **"Open call hierarchy"**

I am not very sure if you are looking for [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), it is used for analyzing the bytecodes

> ASM is an all purpose Java bytecode manipulation and analysis
>   framework. It can be used to modify existing classes or dynamically
>   generate classes, directly in binary form. Provided common
>   transformations and analysis algorithms allow to easily assemble
>   custom complex transformations and code analysis tools.
>
> ASM offer similar functionality as other bytecode frameworks, but it
>   is focused on simplicity of use and performance. Because it was
>   designed and implemented to be as small and as fast as possible, it
>   makes it very attractive for using in dynamic systems*.

Comment: the eclipse way is only for statically defined hierarchies.  ASM possibly could be used.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is please use debugger to see the whole process is being done.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a CGLIB proxy to trace your methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Java profiler tool. There are two well-known profilers - [YourKit Java Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/) and [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).

I prefer first one, but you can try both and make your choice.