# Java - Hiding update functions in project

Tags: java

I'm creating simple game engine in Java and I've got some packages like a:

- Game
- Input
- Time
- Graphics

Each package handles a lot of classes, most of them have (And should have) public access. Let's focus on one most important class called `MouseInput`.

`MouseInput` class handles ONLY public static methods like a `getMousePosition(MouseAxis axis) {...}` but it also handles some methods like a `updateMousePosition() {...}`.

And now I want to make this method (`updateMousePosition()`)  callable ONLY by `GameBase` class that is inside Game package.

P.s. I don't want to put all those classes in one package! I want to separate them to don't make my project messy.

2th P.s. All those methods that I want to make callable only by `GameBase` are static.

Comment: Thats not possible. You can make them package-privat, but there is no concept of `friend` in Java (as there is in c++)

Comment: But I know some libraries/applications that blocks access to some methods somehow.

Comment: They use package-private methods

Comment: I said that I want to separate those classes. I know it's possible to achieve "friend" effect but not directly by telling Java to make another class friend, but it's very different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to restrict who can call even public method by checking the [call stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706292/determining-current-call-stack-for-diagnostic-purposes). This adds some code to the method receiving the call but any "wrong" calls can be rejected.